# Show / Hide Text Box Using Radio Buttons

Tags: hide-elements

I have a column titled "Operations" with 2 radio button options, "Show" and "Hide". When users click the "Show" button I want the text box, column name "Was Hidden", to show up. When they click the "Hide" button I want the text box to go away. I have this so far which doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('H3.ms-standardheader:contains("Was Hidden")').closest("tr").hide();//Hide the text box
if($('span[title="Show"]').closest("td").find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked'))
{
$('H3.ms-standardheader:contains("Was Hidden")').closest("tr").show();
}
else if($('span[title="Hide"]').closest("td").find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked'))
{
$('H3.ms-standardheader:contains("Was Hidden")').closest("tr").hide();
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

First problem I see is that you are incorrectly selecting your elements. None of them are H3 elements, so that was your primary issue.  Their classes had h3' in them, so I can see the confusion.  Anyways - heres some code that works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $text = $('input[title="Was Hidden"]').closest("tr");
        var $buttons = $('input[id^="Operations"]');

        $text.toggle($buttons.filter('[value="Show"]').is(':checked'));

        $buttons.change(function(){
            var $self = $(this);
            $text.toggle($self.is('[value="Show"]'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm having the text box either be shown or hidden off the bat by the proper radio button, but if you require it to always be hidden, remove the $text.toggle.. and make it $text.hide() instead

Answer (score 0):

### Why code?

Use CSS pseudo selectors to check if the first option is checked and add content after the label

```
input[type="radio"]:nth-child(1):checked+label:after{ 
  color:green;
  content:'Was Hidden';
}
```

Comment: I'm still new to this whole coding thing. I'm going through existing code we have and trying to recreate the functionality. If there are easier/faster ways to do something like this that would be great. Sadly I don't know where in NewForm.aspx to put the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Messed around some more and got it to work. Had to add the line with "Operations".

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('H3.ms-standardheader:contains("Was Hidden")').closest("tr").hide();//Hide the text box
    $('H3.ms-standardheader:contains("Operations")').closest("tr").find('input[type="radio"]').change(function()
    {
        if($('span[title="Show"]').closest("td").find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('H3.ms-standardheader:contains("Was Hidden")').closest("tr").show();
        }
            else if($('span[title="Hide"]').closest("td").find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('H3.ms-standardheader:contains("Was Hidden")').closest("tr").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```